# Having a util class call methods of an interface when the util class method names match each class implementation instead of the interface

Tags: java, jaxb, auto-generate

To start, I apologize for the weird title.  I didn't really know how to title this.

We have a class "Factory" that contains a method for each attribute that exists in beans that were generated.  Each method of the Factory class is named in a way that relates to the specific class containing the attribute, and is meant to create a JAXBElement of that attribute.  Unfortunately, this class is also auto-generated.  It looks like so:

```
public class Factory {
    private final static QName _MyClassImpl1Attribute1Name_QNAME = new QName("urn:some.urn", "attribute1Name");
    private final static QName _MyClassImpl1Attribute2Name_QNAME = new QName("urn:some.urn", "attribute2Name");

    private final static QName _MyClassImpl2Attribute1Name_QNAME = new QName("urn:some.urn", "attribute1Name");
    private final static QName _MyClassImpl2Attribute2Name_QNAME = new QName("urn:some.urn", "attribute2Name");

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "urn:some.urn", name = "attribute1Name", scope = MyClassImpl1.class)
    public JAXBElement<String> createMyClassImpl1Attribute1Name(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(_MyClassImpl1Attribute1Name_QNAME, String.class, MyClassImpl1.class, value);
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Boolean}{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "urn:some.urn", name = "attribute2Name", scope = MyClassImpl1.class)
    public JAXBElement<Boolean> createMyClassImpl1Attribute2Name(Boolean value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Boolean>(_MyClassImpl1Attribute2Name_QNAME, Boolean.class, MyClassImpl1.class, value);
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "urn:some.urn", name = "attribute1Name", scope = MyClassImpl2.class)
    public JAXBElement<String> createMyClassImpl2Attribute1Name(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(_MyClassImpl2Attribute1Name_QNAME, String.class, MyClassImpl2.class, value);
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Boolean}{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "urn:some.urn", name = "attribute2Name", scope = MyClassImpl2.class)
    public JAXBElement<Boolean> createMyClassImpl2Attribute2Name(Boolean value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Boolean>(_MyClassImpl2Attribute2Name_QNAME, Boolean.class, MyClassImpl2.class, value);
    }
}
```

The issue here is that each method name matches a class name.  There's no method that says "create attribute of interface", which would allow 1 method to work for all implementations of that interface.  Again, Factory cannot be modified.  In fact, the only class that CAN be modified is this interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    JAXBElement<String> getAttribute1Name;
    void setAttribute1Name(String attribute1Value);
    JAXBElement<Boolean> getAttribute2Name;
    void setAttribute2Name(Boolean attribute2Value);
}
```

Here are the 2 generated classes (leaving off some xml tags that shouldn't be relevant here)

```
public class MyClassImpl1 implements MyInterface {
    private String attribute1Name;
    private Boolean attribute2Name;

    public JAXBElement<String> getAttribute1Name() {
        return attribute1Name;
    }

    public void setAttribute1Name(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.attribute2Name = value;
    }

    public JAXBElement<Boolean> getAttribute2Name() {
        return attribute2Name;
    }

    public void setAttribute2Name(JAXBElement<Boolean> value) {
        this.attribute2Name = value;
    }
}


public class MyClassImpl2 implements MyInterface {
    private String attribute1Name;
    private Boolean attribute2Name;

    public JAXBElement<String> getAttribute1Name() {
        return attribute1Name;
    }

    public void setAttribute1Name(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.attribute2Name = value;
    }

    public JAXBElement<Boolean> getAttribute2Name() {
        return attribute2Name;
    }

    public void setAttribute2Name(JAXBElement<Boolean> value) {
        this.attribute2Name = value;
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I make an interface call for a setter, because the factory doesn't know which method (class specific name) to call.

```
public class AnotherClass {

    public void anotherMethod(MyInterface myInterface) {
        Factory factory = new Factory();
        String value1 = "Some String Value";
        Boolean value2 = true;                
        myInterface.setAttribute1Name(factory.<I need correct method here>(value1));
        myInterface.setAttribute2Name(factory.<I need correct method here>(value2));
    }
}
```

I might be able to do this with reflection, but I'm not too good with it and, quite frankly, I don't like having to.  But here's something that *might* work. 
 Putting this on the MyInterface:

```
default JAXBElement getClassImplJaxbElement(Object attributeValue, String attributeToSet, Factory factory) {

    String factoryMethodName = "create" + this.getClass().getName() + attributeToSet;
    Expression attributeGetter = new Expression(factory, factoryMethodName, new Object[]{attributeValue});
    try {
        attributeGetter.execute();
        return (JAXBElement) attributeGetter.getValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MyRuntimeException(String.format("Failed to create JAXBElement for attribute '%s' and value '%s'.", attributeToSet, attributeValue), e);
    }
}
```

What especially sucks about that is that I would have to call that new method everywhere that I want to call the setter on the interface, which means slow reflection everytime.  Anybody know a way of doing this?  Again, can't modify the ClassImpls and can't modify the Factory.

The classes are generated via .xsd files and the maven plugin maven-jaxb22-plugin.  I'm able to generate a class that implements an interface by adding the jaxb2-basics plugin.

Comment: How are these Factory classes generated, some JAXB tool?

Comment: using the maven-jaxb22-plugin plugin. Also, there's only one Factory class, but a bunch of interface implementations, which are generated via an xsd file (also through the maven-jaxb22-plugin). My understanding of the plugin isn't all that great, but you give a configuration in the plugin that defines where the schema is (xsd files), where you want to generate the classes, etc.